# Split string based on alternating character in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to go about splitting a string like

```
"111110000011110000111000"
```

into a vector

```
[1] "11111" "00000" "1111" "0000" "111" "000"
```

where "0" and "1" can be any alternating characters.

Comment: Do you mean performance efficient or code (readability) efficient?

Comment: @freekvd Sorry, meant readability efficient.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Try

```
strsplit(str1, '(?<=1)(?=0)|(?<=0)(?=1)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "11111" "00000" "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"
```

#### Update

A modification of @rawr's solution with `stri_extract_all_regex`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(str1, '(?:(\\w))\\1*')[[1]]
#[1] "11111" "00000" "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"  


stri_extract_all_regex(x1, '(?:(\\w))\\1*')[[1]]
#[1] "11111" "00000" "222"   "000"   "3333"  "000"   "1111"  "0000"  "111"  
#[10] "000"  

stri_extract_all_regex(x2, '(?:(\\w))\\1*')[[1]]
#[1] "aaaaa"   "bb"      "ccccccc" "bbb"     "a"       "d"       "11111"  
#[8] "00000"   "222"     "aaa"     "bb"      "cc"      "d"       "11"     
#[15] "D"       "aa"      "BB"
```

#### Benchmarks

```
library(stringi) 
set.seed(24)
x3 <- stri_rand_strings(1, 1e4)

akrun <- function() stri_extract_all_regex(x3, '(?:(\\w))\\1*')[[1]]
#modified @thelatemail's function to make it bit more general
thelate <- function() regmatches(x3,gregexpr("(?:(\\w))\\1*", x3, 
            perl=TRUE))[[1]]
rawr <- function() strsplit(x3, '(?<=(\\w))(?!\\1)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
ananda <- function() unlist(read.fwf(textConnection(x3), 
                rle(strsplit(x3, "")[[1]])$lengths, 
                colClasses = "character"))
Colonel <- function() with(rle(strsplit(x3,'')[[1]]), 
   mapply(function(u,v) paste0(rep(v,u), collapse=''), lengths, values))

Cryo <- function(){
   res_vector=rep(NA_character_,nchar(x3))
  res_vector[1]=substr(x3,1,1)
  counter=1
  old_tmp=''

   for (i in 2:nchar(x3)) {
    tmp=substr(x3,i,i)
    if (tmp==old_tmp) {
    res_vector[counter]=paste0(res_vector[counter],tmp)
    } else {
    res_vector[counter+1]=tmp
    counter=counter+1
    }
  old_tmp=tmp
   }

 res_vector[!is.na(res_vector)]
  }


 richard <- function(){
     cs <- cumsum(
     rle(stri_split_boundaries(x3, type = "character")[[1L]])$lengths
   )
   stri_sub(x3, c(1, head(cs + 1, -1)), cs)
  }

 nicola<-function(x) {
   indices<-c(0,which(diff(as.integer(charToRaw(x)))!=0),nchar(x))
   substring(x,indices[-length(indices)]+1,indices[-1])
 }

 richard2 <- function() {
  cs <- cumsum(rle(strsplit(x3, NULL)[[1L]])[[1L]])
  stri_sub(x3, c(1, head(cs + 1, -1)), cs)
 }

system.time(akrun())
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.003   0.000   0.003 

system.time(thelate())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.272   0.001   0.274 

system.time(rawr())
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.397   0.001   0.398 

system.time(ananda())
#  user  system elapsed 
# 3.744   0.204   3.949 

system.time(Colonel())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.154   0.001   0.154 

system.time(Cryo())
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.220   0.005   0.226 

system.time(richard())
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.007   0.000   0.006 

system.time(nicola(x3))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.190   0.001   0.191
```

On a slightly bigger string,

```
set.seed(24)
x3 <- stri_rand_strings(1, 1e6)

system.time(akrun())
#user  system elapsed 
#0.166   0.000   0.155 
system.time(richard())
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.606   0.000   0.569 
system.time(richard2())
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.518   0.000   0.487 

system.time(Colonel())
#  user  system elapsed 
# 9.631   0.000   9.358 


library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(richard(), richard2(), akrun(), times=20L, unit='relative')
 #Unit: relative
 #     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 # richard() 2.438570 2.633896 2.365686 2.315503 2.368917 2.124581    20   b
 #richard2() 2.389131 2.533301 2.223521 2.143112 2.153633 2.157861    20   b
 # akrun() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20  a
```

**NOTE:**  Tried to run the other methods, but it takes a long time

#### data

```
str1 <- "111110000011110000111000"
x1 <- "1111100000222000333300011110000111000"
x2 <- "aaaaabbcccccccbbbad1111100000222aaabbccd11DaaBB"
```

Answer (score 30):

Variation on a theme:

```
x <- "111110000011110000111000"
regmatches(x,gregexpr("1+|0+",x))[[1]]
#[1] "11111" "00000" "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"
```

Answer (score 24):

You could probably make use of `substr` or `read.fwf` along with `rle` (though it is unlikely to be as efficient as any regex-based solution):

```
x <- "111110000011110000111000"
unlist(read.fwf(textConnection(x), 
                rle(strsplit(x, "")[[1]])$lengths, 
                colClasses = "character"))
#      V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6 
# "11111" "00000"  "1111"  "0000"   "111"   "000"
```

One advantage of this approach is that it would work even with, say:

```
x <- paste(c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 2), rep("c", 7),
             rep("b", 3), rep("a", 1), rep("d", 1)), collapse = "")
x
# [1] "aaaaabbcccccccbbbad"

unlist(read.fwf(textConnection(x), 
                rle(strsplit(x, "")[[1]])$lengths, 
                colClasses = "character"))
#        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6 
#   "aaaaa"      "bb" "ccccccc"     "bbb"       "a"       "d"
```

Answer (score 21):

Another way would be to add whitespace between the alternating digits. This would  work for any two, not just 1s and 0s. Then use `strsplit` on the whitespace:

```
x <- "111110000011110000111000"

(y <- gsub('(\\d)(?!\\1)', '\\1 \\2', x, perl = TRUE))
# [1] "11111 00000 1111 0000 111 000 "


strsplit(y, ' ')[[1]]
# [1] "11111" "00000" "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"
```

Or more succinctly as @akrun points out:

```
strsplit(x, '(?<=(\\d))(?!\\1)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "11111" "00000" "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"
```

also changing `\\d` to `\\w` works also

```
x  <- "aaaaabbcccccccbbbad"
strsplit(x, '(?<=(\\w))(?!\\1)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "aaaaa"   "bb"      "ccccccc" "bbb"     "a"       "d"      

x <- "111110000011110000111000"
strsplit(x, '(?<=(\\w))(?!\\1)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "11111" "00000" "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"
```

You could also use `\K` (rather than explicitly using the capture groups, `\\1` and `\\2`) which I don't see used a lot nor do I know how to explain it :}

AFAIK `\\K` resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included, basically throwing away everything matched up to that point.

```
x <- "1111100000222000333300011110000111000"
(z <- gsub('(\\d)\\K(?!\\1)', ' ', x, perl = TRUE))
# [1] "11111 00000 222 000 3333 000 1111 0000 111 000 "
```

Comment: You may shorten the code to `strsplit(x, '(?<=(\\d))(?!\\1)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]`  (haven't tested it with many cases though :-)

Comment: @akrun I know, i was just wondering if you knew what this  `\\K` thing was doing in a regex

Comment: I think `\\w` approach should work in both the cases.  I don't use `\\K` that much, but I guess you explained it in your post about that.

Comment: @akrun, was just about to make the same comment.

Answer (score 15):

**Original Approach:** Here is a *stringi* approach that incorporates `rle()`.

```
x <- "111110000011110000111000"
library(stringi)

cs <- cumsum(
    rle(stri_split_boundaries(x, type = "character")[[1L]])$lengths
)
stri_sub(x, c(1L, head(cs + 1L, -1L)), cs)
# [1] "11111" "00000" "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"
```

Or, you can use the `length` argument in `stri_sub()`

```
rl <- rle(stri_split_boundaries(x, type = "character")[[1L]])
with(rl, {
    stri_sub(x, c(1L, head(cumsum(lengths) + 1L, -1L)), length = lengths)
})
# [1] "11111" "00000" "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"
```

**Updated for Efficiency:** After realizing that `base::strsplit()` is faster than `stringi::stri_split_boundaries()`, here is a more efficient version of my previous answer using only base functions.

```
set.seed(24)
x3 <- stri_rand_strings(1L, 1e6L)

system.time({
    cs <- cumsum(rle(strsplit(x3, NULL)[[1L]])[[1L]])
    substring(x3, c(1L, head(cs + 1L, -1L)), cs)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.686   0.012   0.697
```

Answer (score 12):

Another approach in case, using `mapply`:

```
x="111110000011110000111000"

with(rle(strsplit(x,'')[[1]]), 
     mapply(function(u,v) paste0(rep(v,u), collapse=''), lengths, values))
#[1] "11111" "00000" "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"
```

Comment: Your function is faster than most of the solutions except the stringi

Comment: Oh nice, I would have belied without testing that `regmatches` was faster! Misbelieve due to the fact I dunno what hides under this function!

Comment: `regmatches` is usually faster, but it may also depend upon the `regex` used.  Here, I was testing for a more general case.  The timings might be different if we test using the same regex in @thelatemail's post for a binary string

Answer (score 9):

It's not really what the OP was looking for (concise R code), but thought I'd give it a try in `Rcpp`, and turned out relatively simple and about 5x faster than the fastest R-based answers.

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction(
  'std::vector<std::string> split_str_cpp(std::string x) {

  std::vector<std::string> parts;

  int start = 0;

  for(int i = 1; i <= x.length(); i++) {
      if(x[i] != x[i-1]) {
        parts.push_back(x.substr(start, i-start));
        start = i;
      } 
  }

  return parts;

  }')
```

And testing on these

```
str1 <- "111110000011110000111000"
x1 <- "1111100000222000333300011110000111000"
x2 <- "aaaaabbcccccccbbbad1111100000222aaabbccd11DaaBB"
```

Gives the following output

```
> split_str_cpp(str1)
[1] "11111" "00000" "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"  
> split_str_cpp(x1)
 [1] "11111" "00000" "222"   "000"   "3333"  "000"   "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"  
> split_str_cpp(x2)
 [1] "aaaaa"   "bb"      "ccccccc" "bbb"     "a"       "d"       "11111"   "00000"   "222"     "aaa"     "bb"      "cc"      "d"       "11"     
[15] "D"       "aa"      "BB"
```

And a benchmark shows it's about 5-10x faster than R solutions.

```
akrun <- function(str1) strsplit(str1, '(?<=1)(?=0)|(?<=0)(?=1)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]

richard1 <- function(x3){
  cs <- cumsum(
    rle(stri_split_boundaries(x3, type = "character")[[1L]])$lengths
  )
  stri_sub(x3, c(1, head(cs + 1, -1)), cs)
}

richard2 <- function(x3) {
  cs <- cumsum(rle(strsplit(x3, NULL)[[1L]])[[1L]])
  stri_sub(x3, c(1, head(cs + 1, -1)), cs)
}

library(microbenchmark)
library(stringi)

set.seed(24)
x3 <- stri_rand_strings(1, 1e6)

microbenchmark(split_str_cpp(x3), akrun(x3), richard1(x3), richard2(x3), unit = 'relative', times=20L)
```

Comparison:

```
Unit: relative
              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 split_str_cpp(x3) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20
         akrun(x3) 9.675613 8.952997 8.241750 8.689001 8.403634 4.423134    20
      richard1(x3) 5.355620 5.226103 5.483171 5.947053 5.982943 3.379446    20
      richard2(x3) 4.842398 4.756086 5.046077 5.389570 5.389193 3.669680    20
```

Comment: Wait, so my answer is faster than akrun's? Interesting

Answer (score 3):

Simple `for` loop solution

```
x="aaaaabbcccccccbbbad1111100000222aaabbccd11DaaBB"
res_vector=substr(x,1,1)

for (i in 2:nchar(x)) {
  tmp=substr(x,i,i)
  if (tmp==substr(x,i-1,i-1)) {
    res_vector[length(res_vector)]=paste0(res_vector[length(res_vector)],tmp)
  } else {
    res_vector[length(res_vector)+1]=tmp
  }
}

res_vector

#[1] "aaaaa"  "bb"  "ccccccc"  "bbb"  "a"  "d"  "11111"  "00000"  "222"  "aaa"  "bb"  "cc"  "d"  "11"  "D"  "aa"  "BB"
```

Or a maybe a little bit faster with a pre-allocated results vector

```
x="aaaaabbcccccccbbbad1111100000222aaabbccd11DaaBB"
res_vector=rep(NA_character_,nchar(x))
res_vector[1]=substr(x,1,1)
counter=1
old_tmp=''

for (i in 2:nchar(x)) {
  tmp=substr(x,i,i)
  if (tmp==old_tmp) {
    res_vector[counter]=paste0(res_vector[counter],tmp)
  } else {
    res_vector[counter+1]=tmp
    counter=counter+1
  }
  old_tmp=tmp
}

res_vector[!is.na(res_vector)]
```

Comment: Your second function is faster, but still behind Colonel's approach. +1

Comment: I will add another modification that makes it a little bit faster. :)

Comment: I am trying to run your function on 1e6 character string.  It takes a long time.

Comment: Yes, does not seem to scale that well.

Comment: Only a little bit faster for the 1e4 vector. But still slow for the 1e6 vector.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
s <- "111110000011110000111000"

spl <- strsplit(s,"10|01")[[1]]
l <- length(spl)
sapply(1:l, function(i) paste0(spl[i],i%%2,ifelse(i==1 | i==l, "",i%%2)))

# [1] "11111" "00000" "1111"  "0000"  "111"   "000"
```

Comment: Fyi, typical to just do `sapply(seq_along(spl), ...)` rather than bothering to extract its length as a separate var.