# counting different length substrings of consecutive characters in R

Tags: r, counting, substring

I have a datset consisting of a large number character strings of length 12, drawn from a two state alphabet (z,x). Here are two examples.

```
  data <- c("zzxzzzxzzzzx","zzzxxzzzzzzx")
```

I wish to count the frequency of substrings which consist of sequences of consecutive "z's".

In this example the required frequencies are,

"zz", 1 (data[1] only)

"zzz", 2 (1 in each of data[1] and data[2])

"zzzz", 1 (in data[1] only)

"zzzzzz", 1 (in data[2} only

Comment: I think OP is looking for the counts of /potentially pairwise overlapping/ substrings.

Comment: @BadZen Based on the expected frequency showed, we get that by using the code

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right.  I misread second line as meaning "2 (in data[1]".  But it would be 3 even, and not 2.   Nevermind.

Comment: some helpful code in this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383296/r-split-string-based-on-alternating-character)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is what you wanted

```
 library(stringi)
 table(unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(data, '(?:(z+))\\1*')))
 #    zz    zzz   zzzz zzzzzz 
 #    1      2      1      1
```

Or this

```
  table(unlist(lapply(stri_extract_all_regex(data,
                             '(?:(z+))\\1*'), unique)))
  #  zz    zzz   zzzz zzzzzz 
  #   1      2      1      1
```

Comment: This certainly solves the problem (so thanks v. much): however I'm afraid I have no idea why it works. Is it possible to have some intuition about what the symbolic bit '(?: etc is doing? It would help me (and maybe others) to generalize to other similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
table(unlist(strsplit(gsub('x{1,2}',' ',data),' ')))
```